# Restore shopt -s nocaseglob setting to default in OS X

Tags: macos, bash

In trying to make Bash for OSX <kbd>TAB</kbd>-Auto-Completion to be Case-insensitive, I followed a suggestion to run these commands:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

How do I restore the above settings to the OS X default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that you added these commands in a script or in one of your dotfiles (`.bash_profile`, etc.), or that you simply ran the commands in the Terminal itself?

If you just ran the commands in the Terminal, simply start a new session, and the defaults should be restored.  Open a new Terminal tab or Window and see if the normal functionality is restored, which it should be.

These settings should not affect the entire system unless they get automatically loaded in a file that is sourced when each session loads, in which case, you can simply remove the entry from your `.bash_profile` or wherever it was added in the first place.

You can double-check to see if the settings are getting automatically loaded in your `.bash_profile` by executing `sudo -s` to become `root`, at which point `root's` dotfiles get loaded, which take precedence over the previous user.  If it works normally as root, go digging in your own `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` and remove these commands/settings.  Default functionality should be restored the next time you load a shell session.

Answer (score 2):

**A first solution**
To restore a situation you **have to know the previous one.**
The commands `bind` and `shopt` are so *cosy* that among the few options they present, there is one (`-p` for the first and `-v` for the second) that give the **output in a format  usable, almost directly, to restore them**:

```
shopt -p   | grep nocaseglob               # shopt -u nocaseglob
bind  -v   | grep completion-ignore-case   # set completion-ignore-case off
```

The output is reported above after the `#` sign.
Once you know the starting value you can create a couple of alias to go in the *Ignore More* (`IgnoreGo`) and to come out (`IgnoreExit`) from it:

```
alias IgnoreGo="shopt -s nocaseglob; bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'"
alias IgnoreExit="shopt -u nocaseglob; bind 'set completion-ignore-case off'"
```

You can put this alias with the other of your configuration shell (typically in `~/.bash_aliases`  or `~/.bashrc`) and use when you want. Problem is that those are blind, they will not see the actual situation of your shell.

**A better solution**
Just to make all this independent from your knowledge of those variable values, and a little bit more complex, you can create a function (`Store`) to create an alias (`ReStore`) to go back, whatever was the initial situation.

```
 Store(){ alias ReStore="$(shopt -p|grep nocaseglob); \
          bind '$(bind -v|grep completion-ignore-case)'"; }
```

Even this can be written in the configuration file for your shell (see above). Each time with `Store` you freeze the actual situation and with `ReStore` you re-establish the last one *freezed*.
<sub>Note that the `\` has to be the last character of the line to split the command in a more readable format on two lines.</sub>

**Note**
On my system to complete a command (e.g. to navigate with `cd`) it is enough to give the `bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'` to enable the ignore case, even when `nocaseglob` is `off`.
The `nocaseglob` on is needed for the pathname expansion.  It exists even the `nocasematch` for the patterns. `help bash` to read more...

**Help on the commands**
The commands `bind` and `shopt` are built in of the shell. It means that to ask the manual for their use you need to use `help` instead of `man`.
To have only a human readable output you can use

```
shopt    | grep nocaseglob               # nocaseglob      on 
bind -V  | grep completion-ignore-case   # completion-ignore-case is set to `off'
```

Answer (score 1):

As read in [Bash manual # 4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html), this is the way to enable/disable `shopt` values:

> **-s** → Enable (set) each optname.
>
> **-u** → Disable (unset) each optname.

Similarly, you can disable the `completion-ignore-case` option with:

```
bind 'set completion-ignore-case off'
```